# Ng-table change page action on second click (not on first)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breeze, ngtable

in html view

```
   <table ng-table="tableParams1" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed  ">
        <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
            <td data-title="'id'">{{user.id}}</td>
            <td data-title="'name'">{{user.name}}</td>
            <td data-title="'studentKey'">{{user.studentKey}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

in js code

```
  $timeout($scope.tableParams1 = new ngTableParams({
                page: 1,
                count: 5,
            }, {
                getData: function ($defer, params) {
                    var page = params.page() - 1;
                    var paramsCount = params.count();
                    breezeCommon.getByPaging(manager, "Student", "id asc", page, paramsCount)
                        .then(function(res) {
                            params.total(res.inlineCount);
                            $defer.resolve(res.results);
                        })
                        .catch(function(res) {
                            debugger
                        });
                },
            }),1000);
```

after first click i get the data correctly but it doesn't append to ng-table and after Second Click  ng-table fill with data

Comment: why is there a $timeout ?

Comment: $timeout is angular js timeout

Comment: I don't know why your using a timeout (yes we know `$timeout` is an ng component; why are you using it?). I don't know what `$defer` is either nor why your need it because a breeze query returns a `$q` promise. Maybe you're missing a `$rootScope.$apply` somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in Mohebifar's and Wards's comments above you do not need to use angulars timeout service in this. The $defer param though is something that is passed to the "getdata" callback from the ngTable directive itself (actualy is the a $q.defer() result created internaly  by ngTable). Then the deferred object passes to your callback and you decide when to resolve or reject it. If you resolve it you must pass the data you got via service or local array.

Anyway here is a working sample using the github api as a test service.

```js
var app = angular.module('main', ['ngTable']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, ngTableParams) {
  $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                page: 1,
                count: 5,
            }, {
                getData: function ($defer, params) {
                    var page = params.page();
                    var size = params.count();
                    var testUrl = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories';
                    var search = {
                      q: 'angular',
                      page: page,
                      per_page: size
                    }
                    $http.get(testUrl, { params: search, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'} })
                         .then(function(res) {
                            params.total(res.data.total_count);
                            $defer.resolve(res.data.items);
                        }, function(reason) {
                            $defer.reject();
                        }
                    );
                },
            });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-table/0.3.3/ng-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-table/0.3.3/ng-table.min.js"></script>
<div  ng-app="main"  ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
        <tr ng-repeat="repo in $data">
            <td data-title="'id'">{{repo.id}}</td>
            <td data-title="'name'">{{repo.name}}</td>
            <td data-title="'owner'">{{repo.owner.login}}</td>
        </tr>
</table> 
<div>
```